# How to use static Logger in multiple Classes effectively?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I have three classes.

- BaseLogger - Here we are creating static instance of Logger.
- BaseClass - Frameworklevel class containg common methods that are used in almost every class.
- SomeClass - It implements BaseClass and LOGs some information.

**BaseLogger**

```
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;


public class BaseLogger {
    public final static Logger LOG =  LogManager.getLogger(BaseLogger.class);
}
```

**Baseclass**

```
  public class BaseClass extends BaseLogger{
        //Some common methods used throughout Application.
    }
```

**SomeClass**

```
public class SomeClass extends BaseClass{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        LOG.info("Test Log");
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2016-04-28 16:52:11 INFO  BaseLogger:7 - Test Log
```

**REQUIRED** : Can someone guide me how to achieve below.

```
 2016-04-28 16:52:11 INFO  SomeClass:5 - Test Log
```

As I have used static I am not allowed to use **this** in **LogManager.getLogger** and I had to use BaseLogger Class name can someone guide me how to print current class name instead of BaseLagger if LOG called from other classes.

Comment: Don’t do that.  All logging frameworks are designed to be used by making one static Logger per class.  Also, making one “master” class with all the “common methods” is a serious anti-pattern;  make it a separate class that does not require any inheritance, and make its methods public.  Inheritance is not the correct way to share functionality.

Comment: Thanks, for good suggestion. What if we are not using inheritance and making Logger to public static. It will still give same  output not required output.

Comment: Create one Logger per class and make each one `private static final`.  You want every Logger's name to match the class which uses it to log messages, so the log entries clearly indicate their sources.  The cost of doing it that way is negligible.  Even if you have 1,000 classes, 1,000 Logger objects will barely be noticeable in your application's footprint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logger pattern %c defined in the logging frameworks(Java util,apache logging,jboss logging etc ) takes the fully qualified class name from the the class where the logger method is called.

To get the class name the way you require ,you need to adapt your logger pattern to have custom pattern ie %X{classname}

Here ,classname can be set in your class before calling logger using MDC.put(“classname”,com.xxx.xxx)